# Request url is not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I do this:

```
http://localhost:53072/Employee/Delete/2
```

Thats my action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            _provider.Delete(id);
            return View();
        }
```

Why does it not trigger in the controllers action Delete?

Comment: What's the controller name?

Comment: Define "I do this."  If by "do this" you mean you enter that URL in the browser directly then you're issuing a `GET` request (the default when requesting a resource).  The code explicitly filters for `POST` requests with the `HttpPost` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are accessing the url via a browser it will make a `GET` request and your action is a `POST`.

You could either change your request using a tool like fiddler or change your method to this instead:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        _provider.Delete(id);
        return View();
    }
```

You could also omit the `[HttpGet]` as it is the default.

**Update**

In order to make this a post instead of using an ActionLink you could do the following:

Add this to your view, wrapping it in a begin form

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    <input type="submit" value="delete" />
}
```

Leave your action as follows:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        _provider.Delete(id);
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: When I click my Delete Action link why is this a Get? Deletion is a Http Post imho! not?

Comment: An action link issues a get. Wrap it in a form and use a submit button instead.

Comment: @Pascal See update. That is the solution to using a form post instead. :)

Comment: Also please remember to put @Html.AntiForgeryToken() and [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] around this.  Don't want other people deleting users from your DB. :)